# how do you echo multiple images that have the same name as part of the file name in php?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to figure out how to echo all images in a directory that contain the same name as part of their file-name. 
I have files that are being uploaded to my web-server. when uploaded the files are renamed to *108_2.jpg*, *108_3.jpg*... etc.

I would like to echo all images that contain the 108 file-name. This is what I have so far:

```
<img src="../uploads/<?PHP echo $_SESSION['propertyid'].'.jpg'; ?>" alt="photo" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
```

the `$_SESSION['propertyid']` would be the "*108*" part of the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way should make the trick. Just be careful about the path, it might not be the same for the client and the server…

```
<?php
$path = "../uploads";
foreach (glob("$path/{$_SESSION['propertyid']}*") as $filename):
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $path ?>/<?php echo $filename ?>" alt="photo" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!! this works!! So is there any way I can use $_SESSION['propertyid']* instead of the 108*??

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
$files = glob('108*.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which files have that prefix before you display them with a loop. Something like this might help:

```
$files_in_dir = glob('path/to/images/*');
$files_to_display = array();

// Get your session var
$prefix = $_SESSION['propertyid'];

// Get images you're after
foreach ($files_in_dir as $filename) {
    if (substr($filename, 0, strlen($prefix)) === $prefix) {
        $files_to_display[] = $filename;
    }
}

// Output images
$format = '<img src="../uploads/%s" alt="photo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px: border: none;">';
foreach ($files_to_display as $filename) {
    echo sprintf($format, $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` to get images. Example:

```
$id = (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : '108';
$path = 'upload/' . $id . '*';
foreach (glob($path) as $filename) {
     echo '<img src="'.$filename.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more practical than this but it should do.

```
$imgCount = count(glob("../uploads/". $_SESSION['propertyid']."_*.jpg"));
for($i = 1; $i = $imgCount; $i++) {
    $img = '../uploads/' . $_SESSION['propertyid'] . '_' . $i . '.jpg';
    echo '<img src='. $img .' alt="photo" width="100" height="100" border="0" />'
}
```